# Woo Commerce and Paid Membership Pro

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the Paid Membership Pro Wordpress plugin to define several levels of access to online courses like "Basic Modules" and "Advanced Modules". I used Woo Commerce to define two products "#1 Basic Modules" and "#2 Advanced Modules", and sell them for a monthly flat fee. If I use PMPro for checkout the user profile has an entry named package which contains the level name.

If I use the checkout procedure of WooCommerce how can I add the level name of PMPro to the profile?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure if you have set the relevant membership to the product in WooCommerce. Go to WP Admin > Products > Add New and create a new product with the name of the membership, like you have "Basic Modules", so create a product Basic Module membership and select it in the membership setting. In the same way create one product for each membership you have created.

NOTE:  Each membership can contain only one product. You cannot use the same membership to connect with different products.

Also, please make sure to setup the user pages on PMPro as mentioned here:
https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/add-ons/pmpro-user-pages/